# What is the best method to wipe disk with DBAN?

Tags: dban

What is the most effective method of using DBAN to wipe disks such as HDD, SD card,... Please ignore Gutmann method because it only use for old drives. I only care about the security level, I don't care about time.

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence on Gutmann?  Do you mean that Gutmann is applicable only for old drives, or it isn't needed because your drives are old?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use dban? There's better methods for it these days, but tools are OS dependant.

Comment: Well, I use it to wipe my hard disk

Answer (score 1):

With modern drives guttman suggests "a couple of passes of random scrubbing", though many contemporary sources suggest simply zeroing out the drive. In fact, the dban FAQ says the same thing I'd pick something like 10 passes of random data and be done with it.

However there's better ways - such as the [sata secure erase command](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) - using hdparm on linux, though there's also decent dos tools - like [CMR's secure erase tool](http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes/secure-erase.html). Unlike dban, this is a ata command *baked into the drive* and essentially is a low level secure erase.